# Cross domain (on same server) fails to load resource (Safari)

Tags: javascript, safari, resource-loading

I have a problem which only occours on Safari.

My server has alot of subdomains that points to the same place on my server (`/var/www/myproject`)

my main domain is: www.myproject.com a subdomain could be app.seconddomain.com both of these domains points to my server and to the above project folder.

This odd bug results in the grafical error you  can see from the following images:

**How it should be**

[image: Working]

**How it looks on subdomain**

[image]

It looks like it has something to do with an error loading the files cross domain. However the console writes no error so i am kinda lost.

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: where is the  difference? edit: a spotted it the navigation. maby some htttps http isues?

Comment: @RolandStarke both of these are http

Comment: Can do a do network inspect(In Chrome by pressing F12; I do not know the option in Safari) and see if any requests are failing while the page loads?

Comment: @Vasco i did that no requests are failing exepct some images. the two consoles are completely alike